# WOULD usage for future

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

I have read this news about a cyclone in "The Hindu"  news paper of India

> Officials at the regional Meteorological centre in Kolkata on sunday issues warnings that squally winds of 40_50 kmph gusting to 60 kmph are very likely to prevail over North Bay of Bengal and along and off Odisha WestBengal Bangladesh coasts from the evening of May24. "It **would** gradually increase further becoming 90_100 gusting to 110 kmph from 26th morning and increase thereafter becoming 155_165 kmph gusting to 185 kmph at the time of landfall till 26th afternoon" a special bulletin issued by the IMD late on Sunday evening said.

My doubt here is why **would** is used there??  Shouldn't we **will** there?? So what  is the difference between usage of **will** and **would** usage???

Comment: Agreed, it's odd. English in India has different grammar patterns than elsewhere. This may be one of them.